# How to utilize lambda to compare data inside a list?

Tags: c#, list, lambda, compare

I'm making a login system for this app but then I got stuck at how to check if the username and password that user entered are actually on the list.

I did try something like this but it didn't help:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string username)
        {
            try
            {
                list.Find(x => x.username == username);
                return true;
            }
            catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
                return false;
            }
        }
```

There is probably some really easy way to do this that I don't know and can't find, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the Any() LINQ extension method:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string username)
{
    try
    {
        return list.Any(x => x.username == username);
    }
    catch (ArgumentNullException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        return false;
    }
}
```

It will return on the first match.

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like the following:

```
private bool CheckUsername(string username)
{
    return list.Contains(username);
}
```

For info about `Contains` method, please have a look [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bhkz42b3(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: As far as I remember Contains take object not lambda.

Comment: @Zbigniew you remember correct ! My bad, I just corrected it. Thank you very much !